# Running a build against multiple projects with different build arguments

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have a series of projects that need to be compiled and published, deployed to separate directories with separate MSBuild arguments.  As it stands, I have separate builds for each.  For example, project 1:

```
MSBuild Arguments: /target:myTarget /property:PublishDir=\\1.1.1.1\PublishDir1
```

and project 2:

```
MSBuild Arguments: /target:myTarget /property:PublishDir=\\1.1.1.2\PublishDir2
```

However I'd like to merge them into a single build.  The problem I have is that although TFS will allow me to specify multiple projects in the build, the MSBuild arguments apply to all projects.  Is there a quick way I can force a distinct set of build arguments per project, or do I need to create a new build template to do this?

Comment: I can't think of anything that doesn't involve hacking around in the template XAML.

Comment: Do you have a custom MSBUILD script that you are working with? 

While I was working with TFS2008 (the TFSBuild.proj msbuild scripts directly) we had a similar issue to tackle. What we did that time was we edited the TFSBuild.proj file to add additional MSBUILD properties (eg: target_proj1, publishDir_proj1, Target_proj2 etc) this was passed in during the build. Then within the MSBUILD script based on project being compiled we would pass the appropriate properties to the MSBUILD.exe call.

Comment: IIRC TFSBuild.proj files were replaced by WF Xaml files in 2010.  I stand to be corrected on that.

Comment: Yes they were replaced with WF XAML in 2010, that's why I said when I "was". If you are using XAML, then like DaveShaw mentioned, you will have to hack around with the XAML to accomodate your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, you need new build template to pass additional arguments to the template.

But if you are trying to Publish the build output to different directory based on different Project, you can achieve it by setting up same publish profile for each project. Add  publish profile for each Project with same name. you can use File system Publish Method to Publish the output to different directories for each project. Just call the Publish profile in the MsBuild Argument.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Dev
```

Comment: I didn't realise yu could configure publish profiles for non-web apps.  How would I go about this?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't Realize that you are are using Non-web apps. You can't add Publish profiles to Non-Web Apps. I think in your case, you need custom templates or you can try this method   http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/09/06/queue-another-team-build-when-one-team-build-succeeds/

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but it did save me some work trying to change the build definition myself (and it worked) - thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, that you create an MSBuild `.proj` file to execute the builds, i.e.:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Rebuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="Rebuild" >
<!--Execute proj1-->
<MSBuild Projects="Proj1.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Debug;PublishDir=\\1.1.1.2\PublishDir1;></MSBuild> 
<!--Execute proj2-->
<MSBuild Projects="Proj2.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Debug;PublishDir=\\1.1.1.2\PublishDir2;></MSBuild> 
</Target>
</Project>
```

Just point your tfs to this custom `.proj` file.

Comment: Won't that have the problem that all the other stuff the build does (such as get latest source, etc) will be missed?

Comment: I think it depends on how you configure the build. We use the approach I've described and it works OK - I think you can try it and see if it works for you

Comment: I get an error "The target "Build" does not exist in the project." with this.

Comment: @s093294 , I've changed default target (see updated code: DefaultTargets="Rebuild" )

Comment: Just noticed, even though I do Configuration=Release, the packages build by TFS is containing debug files. Not sure where I can configurer it other thant that to do release build

Comment: @s093294 Debug configuration is hard-coded in the example file. Use properties to have it changeable see this line <MSBuild Projects="Proj1.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Debug; ...

Comment: Ye thats what i changed to =Release instead. But think my problem is elsewhere. I created a new question for it. Thanks for the help